# insert different row after first two in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple MySQL query with while cycle. What I need to is after each second entry change `<div id="bigdivider"></div>` into `<div id="productdivider"></div>`
Is it possible? Or I need some function to perform that task?

```
query="select * FROM prekes";
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'"); 
$rt=mysql_query($query);         
echo mysql_error(); 
while($laukelis=mysql_fetch_array($rt)){
    $id=$laukelis['id'];
    $pavadinimas=$laukelis['preke'];
    $gamintojas=$laukelis['gamintojas'];
    $kaina = $laukelis['kaina'];
    $data = $laukelis['data'];
    $foto = $laukelis['foto'];
    $nuoroda = 'info.php';
        if (isset ($_SESSION['user'])){
echo '<div id="pro"><a href="#"><h1>'.$gamintojas.' "'.$pavadinimas.'"</h1></a><img class="float-left" src="prekiu_foto/'.$foto.'"width="187" height="134" alt="" /><p>Kaina: '.$kaina.'lt</p><a href="#" id="buyit"></a></div><div id="bigdivider"></div>';
}else{
echo '<div id="pro"><a href="#"><h1>'.$gamintojas.' "'.$pavadinimas.'"</h1></a><img class="float-left" src="prekiu_foto/'.$foto.'"width="187" height="134" alt="" /><p>Kaina: '.$kaina.'lt</p></div><div id="bigdivider"></div>';
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little confusing by your language whether you're wanting to swap divs every other row , or use `productdivider` every third row. Here's an example of the latter using a counter and swapping between the different divs:

```
// use a counter
$i = 0;
while (...) {
    // first and second of three is bigdivider
    if ($i % 3 < 2)
        $divcode = '<div id="bigdivider"></div>';
    // after every second one, use productdivider instead
    else
        $divcode = '<div id="productdivider"></div>';

    ...
    // replace div part with $divcode
    // obviously use all your other logic still, this is just a sample
    echo '...<a href="#" id="buyit"></a></div>'. $divcode
    ...

    // increment the counter
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable that will keep track whether it is the first or second (if testing whether it is the first or second then you can use a boolean variable otherwise use an integer counter), and do an if/else based on the variable.

The variable should be intialized before the loop, and then toggle the value for every iteration of the loop.

Or you can take an alternative approach by subsituting the while loop for a "for" loop, as in the following code:

```
for($i = 1;$laukelis=mysql_fetch_array($rt);i++)
```

And then in the code use the modulus operator to test if it is the second iteration.

You can use this approach even while using a boolean variable as in the following code:

```
 for($is_even=false;$laukelis=mysql_fetch_array($rt);$is_even=!$is_even)
```